# jQuery that works inside of a function ... but not outside?

Tags: jquery

In the following jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   

    function parse(document){
        $(document).find("entry").each(function(){
            $("#items").append(
                '<h3><a href="#">'+$(this).find('title').text()+'</a></h3>'+
                '<div> '+$(this).find('summary').text()+'</div>'
            );
            $('#items > div').hide();
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'www.---.com', // name of file you want to parse
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parse,
        error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
    });

            //ANIMATION
    $('#items h3').click(function(){
        $(this).next().animate({'height':'toggle'}, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');
    });

    $('#footer').click(function(){alert("Why does this work, but not the bouncing panels?")});

});
```

The section marked //ANIMATION works when I place it inside the parse() function, but is very flaky. When placed outside of it, as above, it will not run at all.

Why? I'm really banging my head on the wall trying to understand why it won't run.

Comment: Maybe you could put a running example on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous (essentially runs in a separate thread) and anything executed after it may or may not executed before `parse` is called.  So there is likely `#items h3` to add `click` to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because in `parse` you create the `h3`'s they dont exist otherwise, so the event handler cannot be bound to them.

Use `on` http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
 $("#items").on('click', 'h3',
     function(){
         $(this).next().animate({'height':'toggle'}, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');
     }
  );
```

Comment: downvote explanation please? Would love to know why this is incorrect :).

Comment: This doesn't work either if the h3 items don't exist at the time the event handler is installed.  You have to pass the selector as a .on() argument for it to work with dynamically created elements and use delegated event handling.

Comment: Thank you guys. This was indeed the solution. The flakiness I was experiencing was that the animation would not leave some of the panels open after a click. They would open and almost immediately shut. This code got the animation working and working properly.

Answer (score 1):

When dynamically generating content, use `delegate` rather than `click`.

```
$('#items h3').click(function(){
```

replace with

```
$('#items').delegate('h3','click',function(){
```

Comment: These two statements work identically.   This is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `delegate`, not `on`. Updated.

Comment: even you could use $().live('click',function(){})

Comment: Just wanted to point out the delegate doc for 1.7 says ".delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."

Comment: For future reference, `.on()` has a dynamic version like `.delegate()`  where the dynamic selector is passed to the funtion and the `.on()` version is what is recommended for jQuery 1.7+.

Comment: The jquery docs made that way too confusing. They could really add a simple "TL;DR: JUST USE `on`" at the top of the documentation.

Comment: I believe what you were trying to convey is: `$(document).on('click', '#items h3', function(){});` The `selector` parameter ensures that the event is bound to `document` when it is ready, and delegated to `#items h3` as they emerge.

Comment: It's best NOT to use `$(document).on()`.  You should pick a static parent as close to the dynamic items as possible.  $(document) is why `.live()` was deprecated because of performance problems putting all dynamic event handlers on one top-level object.

Comment: @jfriend00 is correct here, but given the code posted in the question, `document` is the only element we can safely assume *is*, in fact, static in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Alright folks, this isn't nearly as convoluted as people are making it. In order to bind events to the dynamically-created `h3` elements, you need to delegate them from an element that exists at the time of the call (in this case, `document`, since the firing of the event on `ready` means that the document is prepared to have events bound to it). In order to delegate with jQuery's `on`, you need to use the `selector` parameter, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#items h3', function(){
    $(this).next().animate({'height':'toggle'}, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

(`this` refers to the delegated target, not the root element, `document` itself.)

EDIT: I suppose it's worth noting that, for performance's sake, you should select a root element as close in the DOM to the elements you're trying to target with your event as possible, while maintaining its readiness at the time of the initial event binding.

Comment: Finally, someone who got it right the first time!  It would be a LOT better to bind to something much closer to the items than `document` which the OP will know what the options are.  This is why `.live()`was deprecated because it bound everything to `document`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I belive I fixed it by wrapped the function in a blank jquery function.

Comment: What's a blank jQuery function?